# rework onclick html to ajax js function play framework

Tags: javascript, html, playframework, onclick

Please Help

I am fairly new to play framework I have been following a tutorial to build a bookstore all had been going well until I started using a html onclick method for a Delete routine calling a js ajax function. I now realise that my issue is down to chrome not supporting the onclick method but despite many attempts and re-writing this code I have not come up with a solution.

Some of my attempts at re-writing this are still visable but rem out in the code below

show.scala.html

```
   @(book : Book)

    @Layout(book.title) {
    <h1> @book.title</h1>
    <p> Price test : @book.price</p>
    <p> Author : @book.author</p>

    <a class="btn btn-primary" 
    href="@routes.BooksController.edit(book.id)">Edit</a>


    <button class ="btn btn-danger" onclick="sendDeleteRequest(
            '@routes.BooksController.destroy(book.id)',
            '@routes.HomeController.index()'
    )">Delete</button>

}
        <!--<button class ="btn btn-danger" 
    id="sendDeleteRequest('@routes.BooksController.destroy(book.id)',
    '@routes.HomeController.index()')">Delete</button> >
```

custom.js

```
//document.getElementById("sendDeleteRequest").addEventListener("click",DeleteRequest)
    function sendDeleteRequest(url,rUrl) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "DELETE",
        success: function () {
            window.location = rUrl;
        },
        error: function () {
            window.location.reload();
        }
    });
}
```

Thank You

Comment: and where do you load your `custom.js`? what do you get in console? probably that `sendDeleteRequest` is not defined...

Comment: The console gives me the following which is why I think i need to rework the onclick, I have previously reworked it and got nothing in the console when clicking my delete button

Comment: This message from the console
Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Comment: The custom.js is loaded in my layout.scala.html at the end of the body tag
<script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("js/custom.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>